# Loading multiple FactTypes in KieSession

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to load multiple FactTypes in order to support multiple drl files

```
    FactType rootObjectFactType = kieSession.getKieBase().getFactType("kieRule", "Parent");
    Object rootFact = null;
    try {
      rootFact = rootObjectFactType.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    rootObjectFactType.setFromMap(rootFact, dataMap);
    kieSession.insert(rootFact);
```

The code works fine for single root object/ drl file,  is it possible to have to multiple parent objects / drl files so that everything is controlled by drl files.

Comment: What in the _world_ are you trying to do this for?

Comment: I figured out a way for that .,. just wanted to try and control everything from drl files rather than java code

Comment: Control _what_?